# How to get the currenlly logged in username in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the logged on user name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040290/get-the-logged-on-user-name-in-c-sharp)

C# application may be executed either directly (double clicking on exe) or can be executed as administrator (Run as Administrator).

I need to run my application as administrator (Run as administrator) even in simple user account.

I want to get the currently logged in username using C#(But i get the username of admin).

i tried many options like : Environment.Username, WindowsIdentity class etc. It gives me the username of admin(because i have run the exe as admin) not the currently logged in Username.

This is a winForm application developed on .net 3.5. Application Executable is executed with administrator login by a vb script. vb script is executed as soos as the user logs in.

There are many similar queries in this fourm, but all the answers provide the username of the administrator not the currently loggeed in user's username. Hence i have posted this question.

please answer my query. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: without knowing anything else about your application like what type of authentication, which framework, how you are handling logins and sessions it is almost impossible to give any kind of meaningful answer

Comment: Console? WinForms? WebForms? Silverlight? WPF?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of answers here: [Get the logged on user name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040290/get-the-logged-on-user-name-in-c-sharp)

I'd try the Win32 api one first.

Answer (score 1):

You can try querying the session list.

[Retrieving Logon Session Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379437%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You can figure out the actual user that's currently logged in by finding the active session that's not an admin session.

http://pinvoke.net/ has the information on how to call native methods from C#.

Comment: That's a bad reason to downvote an answer. .NET is a managed framework which is not **supposed** to expose such low-level functionality. There is no choice but to use P/Invoke to access that. Either you knew that and down voted maliciously, or you did not know that which means you don't have the moral right to down vote.

Comment: The OP wants a C# answer. Even though you could use unmanaged code, there are managed methods available. Why over complicate things? Regardless, until the OP updates his question with more detail, we can't know which method is the right answer.

Comment: First, I'm not aware of any managed methods that give you list of OS user sessions and such. Second, even if there's a better solution that involves calling managed methods, it doesn't make my answer incorrect; calling native functions from C# is a standard practice.

Comment: Fair enough. If you edit your answer I can remove my down vote.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, the link in C.M.'s answer does point to a page where a C#-only solution is available, hence got my upvote (it uses WMI, however). Not sure if either my or that suggestion would work in the OP's situation, though.

Answer (score -1):

you could use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` and assign it to a `string`.

for example:

```
string username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: No that will return the name of the user that the application was run as

Comment: Thanks for reply. This gives the admin's  username with which i am executing the exe.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the work -

```
AppDomain appDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
appDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

Console.WriteLine(windowsPrincipal.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: Nope, if you are `machine\UserLimited` and you enter UserAdmin's credentials in the run as box it returns `machine\UserAdmin`

Comment: I thought you wanted to do something else. Run the application from 'admin' accound with right-click->Run As Administrator

Comment: Yes, but if the you do right-click->Run As Administrator and the current user is not a member of the Administrators group it will ask you to use a different account. If that happens your code shows that second account.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This gives the admin's  username with which i am executing the exe.