# Get the MyDocuments folder of the currently-logged in user in a c# application running elevated with administrative privileges

Tags: c#

How do I get the MyDocuments folder of the currently-logged in standard user in a c# application running elevated with administrative privileges?

The code `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` returns the my documents folder of the administrator, but not the current user.

I'm testing on Windows 8, though an answer that works for all windows versions would be great

Comment: This might possibly give you an idea on a start for how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873787/when-a-process-is-elevated-how-can-i-get-the-windows-authentication-id-of-the-no  or this might be easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040290/get-the-logged-on-user-name-in-c-sharp

Comment: Running unelevated code, once elevated, is HARD.  Perhaps you can make an unelevated wrapper that looks this up and passes it as a parameter to the elevated program?

Comment: Hey @ben-voigt, that's exactly what I ended up doing. It now bootstraps itself by starting non-elevated, then launching an elevated version of itself with those variables passed in as arguments

Comment: And now, how much do you trust those parameters, considering that they get used with admin rights?  Do you trust the user not to spawn `"ElevatedWriteTheDataHere C:\Windows\System32"` and yell "hey admin, this task is waiting for your credentials!"

Comment: *grin* if they want to screw up their own system, they can go ahead

Comment: ah I get it, they can make it operate on someone else's user account ... well, they are admins anyway.

Comment: And one easy fix is to display the arguments on a screen for review, that asks whether to proceed Yes/No.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63072/discussion-between-bboyle1234-and-ben-voigt).